# How strict is the vertical alignment of equation numbers in literature?

Tags: math-mode, equations

When equations are labelled in literature, do the equation numbers strictly have to be level with the equation? Is it acceptable (or even commonplace) for the equation number to be misaligned vertically? This might happen when the equation is too long to fit on one line and the equation number is subsequently bumped down a bit.

Referring to my attached image, would the formatting of Eq. (3.22) be acceptable? Eq. (3.23) is just an example of something which is obviously acceptable.

[image: equations]

Comment: it is what the AMS implemented for their typesetting so it's presumably acceptable to at least that publisher. However personally if it was as close as you show in the first example I'd squeeze up the equation a bit and make it fit. For example that trailing `.` is not helping

Comment: Personally I haven't seen those numbers in another line than the original one (in professional publications). What I have already seen are equation numbers horizontally shifted into the margin and not in text body anymore. But that's just a personal experience.

Comment: @TeXnician -- the ams is rather unusual in that it has its own print shop, and prints all books and most journals.  the output from the tex production flow is transferred directly to printing plates.  it requires extra attention for anything that is printed in a margin to ensure that it does not get cut off (eliminated) by this process; therefore careful attention is given to keeping everything within the margins.  this practice was carried over from printing with metal type, where it would be impossible to lock up a chase if a line exceeded the specified width.

Comment: @barbarabeeton On the other hand this question is not ams-only, that's why in modern printing there are exceptions using margins. And the question refers to vertical alignment in literature in general. So I would say that today it is not really common to have it broken, but as said it's just a personal experience. That may also differ between countries.

Comment: @TeXnician -- it's true both that other publishers may have different approaches, and also that times have changed.  just thought that the origin of the practice was worth mentioning.  (if you've ever failed to lock up a carefully composed chase, and it spilled, it's not something you easily forget.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the shifted number, and you haven't got space to split the equation over two lines, then it is usually possible to scrunch things up a bit so it fits.

I show this with an equation not unlike the one you show. Whether the resulting output is closer or further from publication quality I leave others to judge.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{3.22}


\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\frac{\left(1+\frac{\tan^2\phi}{\psi_c}\right)}
{
\left(\frac{\tan^2\phi}{\psi_c}+\sin^2\phi\right)
+6\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi+\cos^4\phi\psi_c
}
\right\}^{\frac{1}{4}}
.
\end{equation}
\noindent X\dotfill X


\noindent X\dotfill X
\thinmuskip=0mu plus 1mu
\medmuskip=0mu minus 1mu
\thickmuskip=1mu plus 2mu
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\frac{\left(1+\frac{\tan^2\phi}{\psi_c}\right)}
{
\left(\frac{\tan^2\phi}{\psi_c}+\sin^2\phi\right)
+6\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi+\cos^4\phi\psi_c
}
\right\}^{\frac{1}{4}}
\hspace{-.3em}.
\end{equation}
\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```